# VS Code add spacing after signs = + how to remove the space

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, editor, space, prettier

On my VS code editor i installed prettier extensions and its adding an auto space after the operating signs like "= +".
I would like it to be "=+".
I have tried to search and reinstalled the VS code program.

thanks for helpers!!

Comment: I think you want to use "+=" not "=+"

Comment: i dont want the space between = and +

Comment: =+ is not an operator like += ... so it makes sense , for readability to add a space

Answer (score 1):

You made a syntax error, that's why your code formatter changing it.

Look at this:

Wrong: =+
Right: +=

Ex:

```
let i = 2;
    i += 4;
    console.log(i) // => 6
```

I think you got it.

Comment: Assuming op wants the += shorthand for `x = x +` ... what if they want `x = +n` and just think the space is untidy 